# Symfony: Remove unwanted fields from FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

We have FOSUserBundle which is great bundle to create a quick user management with Symfony. 
I set it up and it created fos_user table in database with lot of fields, in fact these all the attribute of an user entity is really useful and adding the new field in user entity is simple and it is great.

But, Can we remove the attribute from fos_user table without touching the core entity of FOSUserBundle, I mean in my requirement i do not want to use other fields which for_user table have like (last_login,  locked,     expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at) because my client do not need these feature and do not want unwanted fields in schema.

Can anybody please let me know if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible (or recommended) to remove fields in the schema. FOSUserBundle will use those fields in its logic, and will most likely throw errors if they are missing. Even if you don't use them explicitly, the bundle is built to use them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend this bundle with **easy extend bundle** and to extend it with this command :

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
```

EasyExtends is a tool for generating a valid bundle structure from a Vendor Bundle.

This will permit you to build a custom view of you form / list

You can read all this procedure in the documentation :

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html